# What does `M` stand for in the restrict AngularJS option?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, semantics, restrict

What does `M` stand for in the restrict AngularJS option?

From [AngularJS Developer Guide - Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) documentation I see that the:

> The restrict option is typically set to:
>
> ...
>
> 'C' - only matches class name
>
> 'M' - only matches comment

But in order to avoid memorizing that `C` is for class and `M` is for comment, I would like to understand why the `M` is used.

I did not find anything about it on the internet. My guess is that the `m` is the next consonant letter in the word `comment` after the `c` and since the `c` is already taken by comment the `m` is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does exactly what it says it does - allows a directive to be matched to a comment.

Thus:

```
directive('yourDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'M',
        template: '<span>Something in here</span>'
    };
});
```

Can be used like this:

```
<!-- directive: your-directive -->
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it does not answer my question. By the way, it won`t work without the replace option.

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS supports comment directives but it is best not to use them.

From the Docs:

> > **Best Practice:** Prefer using directives via tag name and attributes over **comment** and class names. Doing so generally makes it easier to determine what directives a given element matches.

> > **Best Practice:** Comment directives were commonly used in places where the DOM API limits the ability to create directives that spanned multiple elements (e.g. inside  elements). AngularJS 1.2 introduces `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` as a better solution to this problem. Developers are encouraged to use this over custom comment directives when possible.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Directive Types](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#directive-types)
- [AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API Reference - `restrict`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-restrict-)